# How to correctly write Ajax Post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to send an image url to a node.js server from some javascript using the Ajax POST method. I expect the server to return back some text, however nothing happens and I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is the relevant javascript:

```
function drop(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var imageUrl=evt.dataTransfer.getData('URL');
    //alert(imageUrl);
    console.log(imageUrl);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/examineImage",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"imageRequested":imageUrl}),

        success: function(data){
            console.log("REACHED BACK");
            console.log(data);
            var tags="";
        }
    })
}
```

I believe the function works fine because it displays the url as expected in the console. The node piece also works as expected if I run it by itself outside of a server. Here is the node.js code:

```
app.post("/examineImage",function(req, resp){
    console.log("REACHED");
    var imageURL=req.body.imageRequested;
    stub.PostModelOutputs(
        {
            model_id: "e0be3b9d6a454f0493ac3a30784001ff",
           // version_id: "1ed35c3d176f45d69d2aa7971e6ab9fe",  // This is optional. Defaults to the latest model version.
            inputs: [
                {data: {image: {url:imageURL}}}
            ]
        },
        metadata,
        (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
    
            if (response.status.code !== 10000) {
                throw new Error("Post model outputs failed, status: " + response.status.description);
            }
    
            const output = response.outputs[0];
    
            console.log("Predicted concepts:");
            for (const concept of output.data.concepts) {
                console.log(concept.name + " " + concept.value);
            }
            resp.send(output.data.concepts);
        }
    );

});
```

As I said before the JavaScript piece works fine by itself, and the node.js piece works by itself, so I believe it is something to do with the POST method.  I am new to using node and JavaScript so I apologize if this is an obvious error.

Comment: Did you import `body-parser` to your NodeJS code?

Comment: Is that something I need?

Comment: In order to read the body of the request you need body parser.

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe - body parser is built into express as in `app.use(express.json())`.  No need to separately import body-parser.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 1):

@[user10509686](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10509686/user10509686), I tried your following app.js code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Where we will keep books
    let books = [];

app.use(cors());

// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/",function(req, resp){
    fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(resp);
});

app.post("/examineImage",function(req, resp){
    console.log("REACHED");
    var imageURL=req.body.imageRequested;
    console.log(imageURL);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

With your following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/examineImage",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"imageRequested":imageUrl}),

        success: function(data){
            console.log("REACHED BACK");
            console.log(data);
            var tags="";
        }
    })
```

I found the parameter value at the server side (Node.js). Now, as you told like you didn’t get response, it means there is some issue into your `stub.PostModelOutputs`
Method. You need to further debug into it. My assumption is not getting response from your `stub.PostModelOutputs` and due to that, you are not getting response.